# Javascript modal using class which can be used as a template for multiple buttons on a single page

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, popup

I am trying to code a project that I created with Adobe Muse, the previous project can be found [here](https://sammiidesign.co.uk/Communication%20Infographic/).
On that page when you click on each of the circular buttons you get a pop up / modal box with some text.

Ideally I would like to create a javascript pop up / modal like my previous design, but as a template which uses a 'class', and '.this', so i can use that code across the thirty or so buttons there are on the page. I haven't quite found what I am looking for as everything I have found uses as 'IDs' and is a single button example.

[This](https://github.com/Sammii-HK/communicationInfographic) is the main tree and [here](https://github.com/Sammii-HK/communicationInfographic/tree/master/resources/js) are the .js files, it is what I have so far.

I would appreciate any help or ideas, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

on tag can have multiple class. you should use it.

```
<button class="template other_class1 other_class2" />

<button class="template other_class1 other_class2" />
```

This is separated by a space.

and, id attribute should unique in one html docs. That is desirable.

//edit

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
haha
<button class="modal" id="button1">button1</button>
<button class="modal" id="button2">button2</button>
<button class="modal" id="button3">button3</button>

<div class="button1_modal" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid red; display: none;">
    modal1
</div>
<div class="button2_modal" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid blue;  display: none">
    modal2
</div>

<div class="button3_modal" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid green;  display: none">
    modal3
</div>

</body>
</html>

<script>
    $(".modal").click(function(){
        var _button = $(this).attr('id');
        var isOpen = $("."+_button+"_modal").css('display') === 'block';
        if(isOpen){
            $("."+_button+"_modal").css('display', 'none');
        }else{
            $("."+_button+"_modal").css('display', 'block');
        }

    })
</script>
```

right?

if you want use hover, maybe more simple.

```
<script>
$(".modal").hover(function(){
    $("."+ $(this).attr('id')+"_modal").css('display', 'block');
},function(){
    $("."+ $(this).attr('id')+"_modal").css('display', 'none');
})
</script>
```

arg 1 is function to hover, arg 2 is function to out from hover

Comment: I know about multiple HTML classes. I need to know about how to write a modal with javascript which uses a class so I can use it multiple times on the same page. But thank you for your time.

Comment: sorry. i cant understand use a button multiple time use for modal. i need more information for detail implement.

Comment: then , are you want open & close to modal by one button?

Comment: Please review [this example](https://sammiidesign.co.uk/Communication%20Infographic/). In this example you can see that each circular button opens a pop up window with some information. I would like a way to code one pop up button template, and by using the .this event selector it assures that the script only works for the element which is being currently selected. I would also like to create a modal which uses a class sector so I can use it across all of the buttons on that single page timeline.

Comment: I am open to suggestions. As you can see, I have a lot of buttons in the timeline which will follow the same design so any solution that works is a good solution to me.

Comment: I am having trouble translating your example into what I want but I think it could work and thank you for your input. I have got the modal open but it stays open, and where your example opens and closes with the button click, would it be possible to add a close button? Please refer to 'modal-window.js' where I have tried to implement something. My design preview can be found [here](https://sammii-hk.github.io/communicationInfographic/) and the code can be found [here](https://github.com/Sammii-HK/communicationInfographic)